# include all vim files in a folder

Tags: vim, vimrc

For my `.bashrc` I have a lot of small snippet files in `.config/bash`, like `10-prompt.sh` and so on. In my actual `.bashrc`, I just have the following:

```
configdir="$HOME/.config/bash"

for file in "$configdir"/*.sh
do
        source "$file"
done
```

I'd like to do the same for my `.vimrc`, but I am not that confident in VimL that I could write that.

How would the snippet for `.vimrc` look like that includes all the snippets in a given subfolder? Ideally, I'd like to make a `.vim/rc/` folder where I can put my snippets into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT***

This is @queueoverflow's shorter version:

```
for rcfile in split(globpath("~/.vim/rc", "*.vim"), '\n') 
    execute('source '.rcfile)
endfor
```

***ENDEDIT***

***EDIT***

(removed my stupid answer)

The function below seems to work.

```
function! SourceMyScripts()
  let file_list = split(globpath("~/.vim/rc", "*.vim"), '\n')

  for file in file_list
    execute( 'source '.file )
  endfor
endfunction
```

Add it to your `~/.vimrc` like that:

```
call SourceMyScripts()
```

***ENDEDIT***

Comment: That does not do anything :-/

Comment: Yes, that's an horribly stupid answer.

Comment: So? Do you know the correct answer or what I did wrong then?

Comment: No, my answer was very stupid. I'm currently trying my hands at a solution. I'm not a vimscript wizard, though.

Comment: Thank you for trying! Currently, I just made `cat ~/.vim/rc/*.vim > ~/.vimrc` as a workaround, but if Vim was able to do this automatically, that would be even cooler!

Comment: See my edit. Tell me if it works for you.

Comment: It works, I edited the post since it can be written even shorter.

Comment: Thanks but you shouldn't completely rewrite answers like that. Instead, add the definitive solution as an answer or amend your question.

Answer (score 0):

A very easy way to do this is "`:runtime rc/*.vim`". Of course, this would iterate over each "rc" subdirectory that might exist in each of the directories in `'runtimepath'`, but I doubt that will be a problem.

See:

```
:help :runtime
:help 'runtimepath'
```